# Using virtual fields as join fields in QGIS fails (NULL values in joined fields)

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, null, virtual-field

I have a point shapefile and a CSV file containing various attributes and three columns (here: `street`,`num`,`addnum`) based on which I would like to join both tables like

```
attribute1;...;attributen;street;num;addnum
1;...;100;Goethestr.;10;A
```

Since 'Straße' might be abbreviated or not and lower/uppercase might not be used consistent, I generate a virtual field `adr` for each table upon wich I'd like to build a join by an expression like

```
replace(lower(if("addnum" is null, "street" || "num", "street" || "num" || "addnum")),'str.','straße')
```

I create a join on the point shapefile like this:

[image]

but as a result I get `NULL` values for the prefixed joined attributes/fields:

[image]

What might be the problem? Virtual fields not suitable for joins?
[QGIS 2.14.5LTR]

Comment: Works fine for me (tested on QGIS 2.16.1). This [issue](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/12046) was reported and fixed a few months ago so perhaps try the latest QGIS 2.14.7 LTR or indeed QGIS 2.16 ;)

Comment: You can't imagine how valuable this comment is to me. Our IT service provider is in the opinion that it is not necessary to update the LTRs, thats why 2.14.5, and this strongly helps me argue not to keep old versions :-) +1.

Comment: Let's hope they listen to you! =)

Comment: they do, at least they're working on it!!! @Joseph if I should meet you irl some day, i buy you a beer ;-)

Comment: Great! That's good news! And I would very much look forward to it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, this works for QGIS 2.16. I also downloaded and tested this on **QGIS 2.14.7 LTR** and it works too.

So *virtual fields* are suitable for joins, you just need to upgrade ;)

Comment: easier said then done...